# Is it possible to display svgz on Android?

Tags: android, svg, zip

is there a simple way to display SVGZ images within an Android app. I know that there are a few libraries to display SVG images. But they do not support SVGZ as far as I know.

In case that there is no library that can display SVGZ images, is it possible to unzip the file with java.util.zip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it should be possible to extract the svg file and visualize it with a small lib called [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/).

Small Example:

```
GZIPInputStream is=/*...*/;
PictureDrawable img = SVGParser.getSVGFromInputStream(is, 0, 0)
                               .createPictureDrawable();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this fork of svg-android](https://github.com/josefpavlik/svg-android/commits/master).
It detects svgz automatically, so you can do directly

```
SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.mysvgz);
```

and it is more compatible with the svg definition. In other words, the original version of svg-android can not view many svgs due to lacks of some features.